# Ctrl key combinations don't work on a hp 2510p

Tags: keyboard, ctrl, ctrl-alt-delete, hp-laptop

I have a tricky problem with my corporate Compaq hp 2510p, the ctrl key is not working properly at all times. I belive that it is hooked in some filter chain that processes certain ctrl+[key] combinations which is very annoying.

I would like some pointers on how to proceed when analysing what application/setup can can cause this kind of keyboard filtering to happen.

Anyway some more background info: Ctrl works together with X, C, V. Both in editors and terminals (Ctrl-C, Z etc) but Ctrl-Shift-Esc and Ctrl-Alt-Del does not work. Very annoying so my only option for logging in us using HP's security app. Shift-Arrow works for selecting text, but not Ctrl-shift arrow to select word by word, but Ctrl-Arrow works when moving the caret word by word.

Now the strange thing is that everything works ok with an external USB keyboard so it might be the driver, but still, google yields 0 when searching for the problem description.

I have vm-ware player installed (but not running it), HP Protect Tools installed, if any of these could affect the keyboard driver.

**EDIT**

I'am now running Ubuntu 10.04LTS on the same Laptop and the problem is still there, so I suspect a HW related error. I will try to see if I can find any keyboard analyzer/monitor tool to run in Linux to diagnose the problem further.

Ctrl key works, but not together with other keys such as Ctrl+shift, Ctrl+Alt+Del etc.

**EDIT**

It was a broken keyboard, it has been replaced now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a broken keyboard, it has been replaced now.

Answer (score 0):

This might resolv your problem:

Some function keys or keyboard shortcuts do not work correctly on a computer that is running Windows 7 kb975741

Essential System Updates for Microsoft Windows 7 
http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareDescription.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodTypeId=321957&prodSeriesId=3355633&swItem=ob-77187-1&prodNameId=3355634&swEnvOID=4054&swLang=13&taskId=135&mode=4&idx=2

/Krister

Comment: I am running Windows XP Professional. After googling some more I suspect that HP Credential Manager and WM Ware player does not work together, I will uninstall WM Ware player and see if the problem goes away,